# Why does no one have the "beta" badge?

Tags: bug, beta, badges

Awarded 0 times! But plenty of people have voted 10 times, added 3 posts over 0 score and came on 3 seperate days! Why has no one, myself included, earned this badge? Is this a bug?
[image]

Comment: Might be awarded at the end of private beta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Beta badge is one of the most misunderstood badges on SE. Considering it can only be reached in a very specific timeframe, it doesn't come up often.

A few historic posts:

> you get it for a site when you participate in the private beta for that site. It's way too late to get it for Stack Overflow, but if you commit to a site on Area 51 and ask and answer questions in its private beta, you'll get the badge for that site. - [ChrisF](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152124/269301)

> The beta badge is for those that participated in the private beta week. It is awarded shortly after the public beta starts. - [Rebecca Chernoff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66220/269301)

> You will get the beta badge once the site moves into public beta,assuming you meet the qualifying requirements - [Sathyajith Bhat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81840/269301)

> #### Beta
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Participate actively in a site’s *private* beta phase by:
>
>   - Upvoting or downvoting 10 posts
>   - Making three posts with score > 0
>   - Visiting the site on three separate days
> - All three requirements must be met before the public beta begins (or possibly before the badge script runs)
> - Not awarded on per-site metas, and activity on the site's meta doesn't count towards the requirements.
> - The script for this badge doesn't run until just after the private beta is complete, so you won't earn the badge until that time. This is
>   because [the criteria for this badge were previously
>   undisclosed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105/377214) and this was
>   to prevent people from figuring out the criteria. - [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/269301)

Based on that, I'd say you're too early in the process to see any Beta badges awarded yet. Once the public phase of beta starts, we should see some badges pop up soon enough.